# Change launchScreen color

Tags: ios, launch-screen

My application supported multi-theme. I need to change the launch screen color after user changing the theme.

Is this possible? I tried to set the color in app delegate in `application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but nothing changed.

Comment: You can only change it in the launch screen storyboard file inside Xcode before installing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a launch screen is static and can't be changed in any way at runtime.

Keep in mind that the launch screen is shown before your app is actually running.

Comment: The name says it all - "runtime" vs. "launch time", ha.